# Child elements in the generated XML does not have Parent's namespace - JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I'm using JAXB to generate the classes for marshalling/unmarshalling of XML. The problem is the namespace of the parent apply only to the parent elements in the XML but not to the child classes used inside the JAXB annotated class.

I'm not sure what mistake I'm doing. Below is my xsd and xml and classes.

XSD:

ItemResponses.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://w.com/"
        targetNamespace="http://w.com/"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        version="1.3.2">

        <xsd:include schemaLocation="ItemCommons.xsd"/>

        <xsd:element name="ItemResponses" type="ItemResponses"/>

        <xsd:complexType name="ItemResponses">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ItemResponse" type="ItemResponse" 
        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10000"/>
                <xsd:element name="additionalAttributes" 
        type="NameValueAttributes" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            additional attributes bag, for future use
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="totalItems" type="xsd:integer" 
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="nextCursor" type="xsd:string" 
minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:simpleType name="ItemPublishStatus">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="IN_PROGRESS"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="READY_TO_PUBLISH"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="PUBLISHED"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="UNPUBLISHED"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="STAGE"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="SYSTEM_PROBLEM"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>

        <xsd:complexType name="ItemResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="mart" type="Mart" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            mart where the item would be listed
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="sku" minOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            partner's item identifier
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
                            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="wpid" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            w's item identifier
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="upc" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            UPC
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="14"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="gtin" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="1000"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="productName" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            Title of the product to be displayed on the 
product details page.
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="200"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="shelf" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="1000"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="productType" minOccurs="0" 
maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="1000"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="price" type="Money" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            current price
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="publishedStatus" 
type="ItemPublishStatus" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            item publish status
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="additionalAttributes" 
type="NameValueAttributes" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            additional attributes bag, for future use
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="NameValueAttributes">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" 
minOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            name
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="type" type="ValueType" 
minOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            type
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="AttributeValue" 
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            Set of values for the attribute
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="AttributeValue">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" 
minOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            value expressed in string
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="group" type="xsd:string" 
 minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            list of values
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="rank" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            list of values
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
```

JAXB Classes

ItemResponses.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ItemResponses")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ItemResponses", propOrder = {
"itemResponse",
"additionalAttributes",
"totalItems",
"nextCursor"
})
public class ItemResponses extends GatewayBaseEntity {

    @XmlElement(name = "ItemResponse", required = true)
    protected List<ItemResponse> itemResponse;
    @XmlElement
    protected NameValueAttributes additionalAttributes;
    @XmlElement(required = false)
    protected long totalItems;
    @XmlElement(required = false)
    protected String nextCursor;
    ... getters & Setters.
}
```

ItemResponse.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ItemResponse", propOrder = {
"mart",
"sku",
"wpid",
"upc",
"gtin",
"productName",
"shelf",
"productType",
"price",
"publishedStatus",
"additionalAttributes"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ItemResponse")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class ItemResponse {

@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
protected Mart mart;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String sku;
@XmlElement
protected String wpid;
@XmlElement
protected String upc;
@XmlElement
protected String gtin;
@XmlElement
protected String productName;
@XmlElement
protected String shelf;
@XmlElement
protected String productType;
@XmlElement
protected Money price;
@XmlElement
protected String publishedStatus;
@XmlElement
protected NameValueAttributes additionalAttributes;
... getters & Setters.
}
```

Money.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Money", propOrder = {
"currency",
"amount"
})
public class Money {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected CurrencyCode currency;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected BigDecimal amount;
...getters & setters ..
}
```

XML OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:ItemResponses xmlns:ns2="http://w.com/">
<ns2:ItemResponse>
    <ns2:mart>w_US</ns2:mart>
    <ns2:sku>382</ns2:sku>
    <ns2:wpid>0RC</ns2:wpid>
    <ns2:upc>689</ns2:upc>
    <ns2:gtin>006</ns2:gtin>
    <ns2:productName>LAM 24 x 36</ns2:productName>
    <ns2:productType>os</ns2:productType>
    <ns2:price>
        <currency>USD</currency> <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->
        <amount>24.99</amount>   <!-- PROBLEM HERE -->
    </ns2:price>
    <ns2:publishedStatus>PUBLISHED</ns2:publishedStatus>
</ns2:ItemResponse>
<ns2:totalItems>87</ns2:totalItems>
    <ns2:nextCursor>AoE/G==</ns2:nextCursor>
</ns2:ItemResponses>
```

The package-info.java has the below entries

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    xmlns = {
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "ns2", 
            namespaceURI="http://walmart.com/"),
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "wmSpecs", 
            namespaceURI ="http://w.com"),
            @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsi", 
            namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    },
    namespace = "http://w.com/",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
    package com.w.services.item.setup.query.domain.model.v3;
```

> Money class is not in the same package. How do I include it in the
>   Jaxb class and generate the xml?

Comment: What's the exact problem you are having due to not getting the parent namespaces on the child elements?

Comment: The `Money` type is not included in your question.

Comment: Unable to validate xml against XSD.

Comment: Money type is shown in xsd  and Money.java class

<xsd:element name="price" type="Money" minOccurs="0">

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
   namespace = "http://w.com/",
   elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

to the `package-info.java` of the corresponding package.

Make sure `Money` is in the same package.

I'm also missing the `targetNamespace="http://w.com/"` in your schema.

Comment: package-info.java info added. But Money is not in the same package. It is a library (data-model jar file). How can I make Money Class have the similar namespace as the total xml which I have pasted? 

Thank you for your help !

Comment: targetNamespace="http://w.com/" is now present in the XSD. code formatting issue while posting the problem here.

Comment: Moving **Money** class to the same package as **package-info.java** solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @user9598778 On SO you say "thank you" by upvoting and accepting the answer.